# Conditional 2 and harmony of tenses

Tags: tense-agreement, conditionals

While teaching yesterday I came across two sentences and I got stuck on them.

1. > If somebody offered me to buy a fur coat, I would say that it **is** too expensive.
   > OR
   > If somebody offered me to buy a fur coat, I would say that it **was** too expensive.

Do we generally need to make a step backwards using indirect speech after "would say"?

2. > If something bad happened to my family when they **are** abroad, it would be terrible.
   > OR
   > If something bad happened to my family when they **were** abroad, it would be terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is clumsy and needs to be rephrased:

> If somebody offered to sell me a fur coat, I would say that it is/was too expensive.

This is a hypothetical situation. It is something that you are imagining, not something that is happening.

For such situations, you require the past tense in your example.

> If somebody offered to sell me a fur coat, I would say that it **was** too expensive.

Similarly, you have to say:

> If something bad happened to my family when they **were** abroad, it would be terrible.

You will find lots of sites explaining these rules and how to phrase hypothetical sentences, including these.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would
https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/conditionals-verb-tense-in-if-clauses/